# problem with Associate file type in my program

Tags: c#, winforms, installation

i have this code for Associate *.sdf files to my C# program:

```
 public class FileAssociation
        {
            // Associate file extension with progID, description, icon and application
            public static void Associate(string extension,
                   string progID, string description, string icon, string application)
            {
                Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(extension).SetValue("", progID);
                if (progID != null && progID.Length > 0)
                    using (RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(progID))
                    {
                        if (description != null)
                            key.SetValue("", description);
                        if (icon != null)
                            key.CreateSubKey("DefaultIcon").SetValue("", ToShortPathName(icon));
                        if (application != null)
                            key.CreateSubKey(@"Shell\Open\Command").SetValue("",
                                        ToShortPathName(application) + " \"%1\"");
                    }
            }

            // Return true if extension already associated in registry
            public static bool IsAssociated(string extension)
            {
                return (Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension, false) != null);
            }

            [DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
            private static extern uint GetShortPathName(string lpszLongPath,
                [Out] StringBuilder lpszShortPath, uint cchBuffer);

            // Return short path format of a file name
            private static string ToShortPathName(string longName)
            {
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder(1000);
                uint iSize = (uint)s.Capacity;
                uint iRet = GetShortPathName(longName, s, iSize);
                return s.ToString();
            }
        }
```

and i use it like this:

```
   if (!FileAssociation.IsAssociated(".sdf"))
                FileAssociation.Associate(".sdf", "ClassID.ProgID", "sdf File", @"d:\ICO.ico", @"D:\OpenSDF.exe");
```

i try this too:

```
   if (FileAssociation.IsAssociated(".sdf"))
                FileAssociation.Associate(".sdf", "ClassID.ProgID", "sdf File", @"d:\ICO.ico", @"D:\OpenSDF.exe");
```

my problem is when the file Already associated with another program it wont work !

for example: the `*.sdf` files on my computer Associate to open with `Visual-studio 2008`

i run this code - **and Nothing happens !!**

what i can do ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the keys first then writing your own.